# How to check certificate already installed in keystore by `Powershell`?

Tags: powershell, certificate, keytool

I want to automatically install the certificate when its not installed.
I can check it manually:

```
keytool -list -keystore $Cacerts_trustStore -alias myCertAlias
```

But I want to use this function:

```
#Check keystore file is not existing or keystore does not contains certificate with alias in it
if (-not (Test-Path $Cacerts_trustStore) -or -not (<CheckCertIsExistsByAlias>)) {
    #Call form to find certificate to install
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $dialog.Multiselect = $false
    $dialog.ShowDilog()
    $certPath = $dialog.FileName
    #Installing the certificate
    & keytool -import -alias myCertAlias -keystore $Cacerts_trustStore -file $certPath 
}
```

I tried:

```
if (-not (Test-Path $Cacerts_trustStore) -or -not (keytool -list -keystore $Cacerts_trustStore -alias myCertAlias)) {
```

But, obviously, it's not working because command output is not Boolean.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You want an AND not OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
# Function to check if a certificate with a given alias exists in the keystore
function Check-CertExists {
    param (
        [string]$keystorePath,
        [string]$alias
    )

    $output = & keytool -list -keystore $keystorePath -alias $alias 2>&1
    return $output -match "Alias name: $alias"
}

# Your main script
$Cacerts_trustStore = "path/to/your/keystore"
$certAlias = "myCertAlias"

# Check if keystore file is not existing or keystore does not contain certificate with alias in it
if (-not (Test-Path $Cacerts_trustStore) -or -not (Check-CertExists -keystorePath $Cacerts_trustStore -alias $certAlias)) {
    # Call form to find certificate to install
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $dialog.Multiselect = $false
    $dialog.ShowDialog()
    $certPath = $dialog.FileName
    
    # Installing the certificate
    & keytool -import -alias $certAlias -keystore $Cacerts_trustStore -file $certPath
}
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).